# three20 p31 syntax error with UIAccessibilityTraits

Tags: iphone, three20

i downlaoded three20 p31. when i tried to build i got errors in following places

```
- (UIAccessibilityTraits) accessibilityTraits {
    return [super accessibilityTraits] | UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText; 
}
```

the same function is used in 3 classes.  TTbutton.m,TTLabel.m,TTstyledTestlabel.m
. i simply commented all  funnctions containing UIAccessibilityTraits.Then  my syantax errors got removed. i found out that in my UIkit framework there is no UIAccessibility.h file. is it my sdk problem ? Why UIAccessibility not included in my UIkit ?

Comment: they are using UIAccessibilityTraits only in new versions of Three20. in old versions it was not there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of the iPhone SDK do you use and what version do you compile for? The accessibility traits were added in 3.0.

Comment: am using iphone 3.0 version only. and  compiling for 3.0